# K-Lipschitz surjection to higher dimension

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I am looking for a (family of) *surjective K-Lipschitz* function $f : [0,1]^n \rightarrow [0,1]^m$ where $n < m$. I am more interested in an explicit description of such a function than in a proof of its existence (if it exists...).

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a map cannot exist, as Lipschitz-maps cannot increase Hausdorff-dimension.